# Observable in parallel

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, reactivex

I'm working with Ionic 3 and ReactiveX Observable objects. I've got an Observable through `AngularFireDatabase` with the method `valueChanges()`. I want to filter it in some ways like having some objects with a certain properties in another Observable and sort it too. I use `Observable.forkJoin()` but it doesn't work because my splashscreen doesn't hide. I can attach you some pieces of code if you need. Or maybe you can help me with some example. Thanks

Here is my code

```
Observable.forkJoin([
  this.allParticipants = this.participantsList.valueChanges().map(res => res.sort((a, b) => a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1)),
  this.paidParticipants = this.allParticipants.map(res => res.filter(guest => guest.paid)),
]).subscribe(() => this.splashScreen.hide(), () => this.splashScreen.hide(), () => this.splashScreen.hide());
```

I put the hiding method in all the params to find if in some ways it hides but it doesn't.

Comment: Please add some code in order to let us help you.

Comment: I need to do those operations to store some infos about my participants, is there a way to call them in parallel or in series and how i can wait all the subscription onCompleted methods?

Comment: Have you looked into using the `forkJoin` operator? https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Comment: I will take a look. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work, I don't know why, I edit the question right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `forkJoin` didn't work here because it only emits, when **all observables complete**. `valuesChanges()` didn't complete. Use `combineLatest` or `switchMap`.